# how to add Startapp ads in flutter app android?

Tags: android, flutter, admob, ads, startapp

I want to change AdMob ads by other ads (some personal problems)
how to add Startapp ads in flutter app android?
are there any methods to add startup ads to my flutter app (android)?

Comment: As of now there is no plugin like this, you will have to use `MethodChannel` and do things natively.

Answer (score 0):

StartApp has now been renamed to Start.io, and recently they started supporting flutter, consider checking this link for details https://support.start.io/hc/en-us/articles/4414596841618-Flutter#getting-started-0-0