# Flutter StartApp Plugin

Tags: android, flutter, startapp

My team and I are working on mobile apps and we would like to get by publishing some ads on them. We tried to work with **AdMob** but had some problems with them and we now try to intégrale other systems such as **[Startapp](https://www.startapp.com)**.

The problem is that only **AdMob** has its *Flutter* plugin. I understand that *Flutter* belongs to **Google** like **AdMob** but we thought it was possible to find other advertisers easily integrated in *Flutter* projects.

We are currently trying to create a *Flutter* plugin but we don't know how to do it. We tried to follow some online lessons but these are not really easy to transpose to that kind of problem. We also tried to develop the plugin by looking at the **AdMob** one but we failed.

Does someone know how to use **StartApp** in *Flutter* apps ? Or did someone create a plugin we could use to solde our problem ? We notices that [someone else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55212761/how-to-add-startapp-ads-in-flutter-app-android) is looking for the same plugin.

Comment: I created a mediationgroup in Admob, now I can display inMobi ads using the flutter plugin firebase_admob

Comment: Hello! Did you have to create ad units in inmobi to make mediation work? Also even if inmobi sdk Is not installed on the app will it work fine?

Comment: Start.io (formerly StartApp) has an official Flutter plugin https://pub.dev/packages/startapp_sdk